# Expecting name or unicode delimeter between '('and 'ON' keyword

Tags: sql, teradata

```
    /*
INNER  JOIN 
(
SELECT 
SGSG_CK,
SGSG_ID
FROM ODS_PRD_STG_VW.CMC_SGSG_SUB_GROUP_STG
WHERE SGSG_ID ='H001'
)  SSG 
( ON MPE.SGSG_CK=SSG.SGSG_CK  ) WHERE MMS.GRGR_CK=$$GRGR_CK
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the parens around the join condition:

```
INNER  JOIN 
(
SELECT 
SGSG_CK,
SGSG_ID
FROM ODS_PRD_STG_VW.CMC_SGSG_SUB_GROUP_STG
WHERE SGSG_ID ='H001'
)  SSG 
ON MPE.SGSG_CK=SSG.SGSG_CK 
WHERE MMS.GRGR_CK=$$GRGR_CK
```